# convert JSP that contain JQuery to PDF by using JAVA

Tags: jquery, jsp, pdf

Could someone help me?

I have to convert JSP page to PDF file. That JSP page has HTML tag, JQuery (Sparklines), and retrieves data from MySQL.

I've tried iText, but it doesn't work for my project. My important graph, which is drawn by JQuery disappear when it convert to PDF. (I used iText version 1.4.3. It's very old, but I had a problem with new version.)

I also see many people talk about FOP, Apache PDFBox, wkhtmltopdf, and many things else. However, all of that document is quite hard for me to understand and study by myself. I also tried to use iReport, but I figured that it isn't suitable for my report style.

Note that, I am very new for JSP and not expert in JAVA. Moreover, my project must use only opensource tools.

Answer (score 0):

For ploats generate image in case of jsp. Don't think your beautifull graph generated with jQuery + html5 and canvas will work for pdf.

In case of PDF generation use images.